# ORDER BY with column number in case

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select with the following `order by`:

```
ORDER BY 4 DESC, case when (5 is null ) then 1 else 2 end, 5 desc,10
```

However, apparently, the fifth column is used as the literal `5`, unlike the other expressions:

```
A constant expression was encountered in the ORDER BY list, position 2.
```

What should I do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use the actual column names! That way, any future changes to the columns in your select don't break your order by.

And if you don't believe me: https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal

Answer (score 0):

This is an all around bad idea. Use the column name no matter how long it is.It would be a maintenance nightmare otherwise.You should try to avoid using dynamic sql.